# Timeout during fetching https website using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I have trouble fetching `zomato.com` website using Python and `requests` library.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.zomato.com/san-antonio')
print r.status_code
```

I run this script and get no response. I'm guessing that the problem is https, but I tried it with some other https websites and it worked liked a charm, and 200 was printed to the console.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to pretend you're coming from an actual browser:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.zomato.com/san-antonio', headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"})

print(r.status_code)

# returns: 200
```